# Spacing additional languages

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, english

I have a lot of languages in my documents and suddenly there is an additional spacing when writing english oder greek words.

Here is an example: (between abc und def is an additional space and I don't know whats wrong.

```
\documentclass[
    12pt,
    headsepline,
    pagesize=auto,
    ngerman,
    greek,
    hebrew,
    english,
    russian,
    latin,
    bibliography=totocnumbered,
    oneside
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\usepackage{bidi}%\makeatletter\@Latintrue\makeatother
    \TeXXeTstate=1
    \setmainfont[%
        Mapping=tex-text,%
        Script=Latin%
    ]{Times New Roman} %
    \newfontfamily\englishfont[%
        Script=Latin%
    ]{Times New Roman}
    \setotherlanguage{english}

\newcommand{\engl}[1]{\textenglish{#1}}
\begin{document}
    abc \engl{def}
\end{document}
\endinput
```

Comment: A real MWE is: `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{polyglossia} \setmainlanguage{german} \setotherlanguage{english} \begin{document} abc \textenglish{def} \end{document}`. The same spurious (?) space is when swtiching language using `\begin{lang}` or `\selectlanguage{lang}`.

Comment: Looks like a bug in polyglossia, so report it here: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues

Comment: Is there an easy bugfix possible until this is fixed?

Comment: Similar [situation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406086/polyglossia-how-to-set-frenchspacing-for-all-languages-everywhere?rq=1) but solution doesn't work when switching language **inline**. This behavior is distinctive (only?) to english language, when switching to others langugages there is no such problem.

Comment: I cannot report this bug, because I cannot create an account. Dont know why. Could somebody please post it there. github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues

Comment: This bug seems to be corrected in the next polyglossia [release](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/356).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information.